# iOS determine UIAlertView size

Tags: ios, uialertview

I would like to determine width of UIAlertView before I show it and after I setup it. I need that to put UIImageView into it and adjust its width to width of UIAlertView. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are trying to customize UIAlertView ? Also, for iOS7 you can not add image to UIAlertView. Try custom alertViews on cocoacontrols.com

Comment: Well, actually I can add image to alertView in iOS7 and I actually do it ;). I just need to get its width.

Comment: You added using addSubView ?

Comment: What you are after isn't allowed by Apple see the section marked as `Subclassing Note` on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html you aren't allowed to mess with the `UIAlertView` hierarchy (So adding subviews) or subclass `UIAlertView` it is meant to be used as is. This is meant to be for all `iOS`s but Apple are being more strict with `iOS7` and they will reject your app from the app store for using Private APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a very good idea to try modifying the UIAlertView's height/width or add a UIImageView to it as this might result in your app getting rejected by the App Store. However, [ios-custom-alertview](https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview) is a good alternative.

A sample code would be:

```
CustomIOS7AlertView *alertView = [[CustomIOS7AlertView alloc] init];
[alertView setContainerView:yourSubView];
[alertView setButtonTitles:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Close", nil]];
[alertView show];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, ios-custom-alertview
 https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview